# Dead Acer V5-131 laptop motherboard

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I have an Acer V5-131 laptop. One day I put it on charging and then it suddenly get off and after that it never get on and no light is glowing after that I opened it and checked the output supply of the adopter. It was around 19.5v. When I connect it to motherboard it get decreased to 0.5v. their is no visible damage on the motherboard. I noticed that after sometime of plugging the power adopter an ic aon 7408. It is heating so much. Is it the problem or something else may be. because it's not. starting with battery also

Comment: Could you clarify what "an ic aon 7408" is exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound A MOSFET? http://www.datasheetdir.com/AON7408+N-Channel-MOSFETs

Comment: @DavidPostill - Likely.  There are better ways to indicate that.  For instance indicating its a `AON7408 N-Channel Enhancement Mode Field Effect Transistor` specifically. But in this context a transistor really does not make sense.

Comment: sorry,but I don't understand why it doesn't make sense???